# Create JSON object instead of an Array using LINQ/JavaScriptSerializer

Tags: c#, linq, json, serialization

Hey folks, hope you've all had a good break over the holidays.

I've created a WebService which returns a list of cities and companies within those cities as a JSON string using LINQ/JavaScriptSerializer.

**My code is roughly**

```
var data = from c in db.Companies
           group c by c.City into cities
           select new
           {
               city = cities.Key,
               companies = from company in cities
                     select company.Name
           };

JavaScriptSerializer jss = new JavaScriptSerializer();
return jss.Serialize(data);
```

**That produces the following JSON string**

```
[
  {"city":"Auckland","companies":["Company1","Company2"]},
  {"city":"Wellington","companies":["Company3","Company4","Company5"]}
]
```

*However I want to make the city the key so I can easily search by it*

**For example**

```
[
  "Auckland" : {"companies":["Company1","Company2"]},
  "Wellington" : {"companies":["Company3","Company4","Company5"]}
]
```

**Any ideas?**

Comment: I don't think that's even valid JSON. Are you sur you don't mean curly brackets instead of square brackets?

Comment: Hey @Mark, are you referring to the 2nd one? I manually typed that so apologies for the error.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just an idea... try

```
var data = db.Companies
             .GroupBy(c => c.City)
             .ToDictionary(g => g.Key,
                           g => new { companies = g.Select(c => c.Name) });
```

So this will build a `Dictionary<string, xxx>` where `xxx` is an anonymous type with a single property, "companies" which is a sequence of company names.

Comment: Thanks Jon, I'm getting an exception though `Error    2    Argument 3: cannot convert from 'AnonymousType#1' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEqualityComparer<string>'`

Comment: @Marko I *think* I see the issue there - try the update? (Jon- hope you don't mind me hacking away ;p)

Comment: @Marc: Thanks for that :) Will edit again just to try to get rid of the scrollbar...

Comment: P.S. I'm not sure the title makes too much sense so edit away if you have a better one.